# Strange Tomcat trailing slash redirect domain handling

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I have a Tomcat 6 webserver running my application and I am seeing some very strange redirect behaviour.

I expect to access my application at the internal URL http://appteam.testdomain.co.uk/test and that this will return a 302 redirect to http://appteam.testdomain.co.uk/test/ which then serves up index.html, the front page of the application.

However, a GET for http://appteam.testdomain.co.uk/test currently returns a 302 to http://appteam.testdomain.co.ukteam.testdomain.co.uk/test/

How would I debug this weird redirect and what Tomcat config could possibly be causing this behaviour?

EDIT

For clarity the strangeness here is that a request for

```
http://appteam.testdomain.co.uk/test
```

is being redirected to

```
http://appteam.testdomain.co.ukteam.testdomain.co.uk/test/
```

Note the mangled domain.

EDIT2

@Sean - I am not doing the redirect myself. Something deep within Tomcat seems to be handling this for me. Let me know which parts of the various Tomcat XML files would help to diagnose this and I will post them.

Comment: How exactly are you performing the redirect? Could you paste the relevant portion of your config/code here.

Comment: Hi mchr.  You may have better luck at http://serverfault.com.

Comment: Do you have a tomcat_home/conf/server.xml or conf/context.xml with a <Context> for the test app? Can you post that bit if any? or do you have an Apache web server fronting this Tomcat with some Redirect rules configured in httpd.conf or similar .conf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked out the answer and it is very specific to the way my app is deployed. Tomcat sits behind an NGINX proxy which forwards almost all traffic to Tomcat. The Proxy is used to handle some URLs differently. It turns out that Tomcat is returning a correct 302 to

```
http://appteam.testdomain.co.uk/test/
```

but the NGINX proxy is mangling this into

```
http://appteam.testdomain.co.ukteam.testdomain.co.uk/test/
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour seems not to be an error. Jetty also sends a 302 redirect if the request points to a directory without the trailing slash.

The [Apache URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) contains a section about the *Trailing Slash Problem*.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but my real concern is about the domain being mangled - see my edit above.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I overlooked this part of your question. Then my answer is useless for you.